# Pass characters to slim php 3 routes

Tags: php, slim

Basicaly I want to pas image name  on the Slim route but im getting page not found,
However if i reamove the dot from the image name it works 'image'
this wont work 'image'

```
$app->get('/images/{imageName}', function($request, $response, $args) {
```

Im using Slim3  any idea im new to slim

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is because a filename contains a dot (.) and other invalid characters, which is not supported by the router. For more complex parameters, it is therefore better to use a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

Example:

`https:://example.com/images?filename=image.png`